# Some images are coming blank when picking from gallery in android

Tags: android, image, picasso, android-gallery

I am working on an application where I am trying to load images to my application through gallery. I am using `Intent` to get the image from the gallery. The images stored in internal storage are coming perfectly in the application, but the images stored in external storage are coming blank.

Code to get images from gallery:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
```

This is the code to get the bitmap and absolute path(getPath() returns the absolute path of the image) of the image:

```
Bitmap bm = null;
        String selectedImagePath = null;
        if (data != null) {
            try {
                bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                bm = scaleDownLargeImageWithAspectRatio(bm);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bytes);
                byte[] byteArray = bytes.toByteArray();
                strProfileImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                selectedImagePath = getPath(HomeScreenActivity.this, data.getData());
                Log.e("ImagePath Gallery", data.getData().toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                    Uri currentImageUri = null;
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
                        // wrap File object into a content provider. NOTE: authority here should match authority in manifest declaration
                        currentImageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(HomeScreenActivity.this, "com.example.sravanthiv.consumermobileapp_nonclinical_android.fileprovider", new File(selectedImagePath));  // use this version for API >= 24
                    } else {
                        currentImageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(selectedImagePath));
                    }
                }
```

I am using the `currentImageUri` to load the images in my application. But some are coming blank(stored in external storage) and some are coming perfect(stored in internal storage).

**I am using Picasso to load images:**    `Picasso.with(mContext).load(Uri.parse(imagesList.get(currentPosition))).resize(135,135).centerCrop().into(holder.selfie_Imageview);`

**Its not able to load this path:**
`content://com.example.android.fileprovider/all_dirs/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20171226_161309.jpg`

**But its able to load this path:**
`content://com.example.android.fileprovider/all_dirs/IMG_20171226_161309.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one solution:

```
private void galleryIntent() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, Util.SELECT_FILE);
}
```

**`onActivityResult` do this :**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == Util.SELECT_FILE) {
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
        } 
    }

}
```

**Get result from gallery selected image**

```
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    if (data != null) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        getImageRealPath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
        if (getImageRealPath == null) {
            // need to code download google photo code
        }
        file = new File(getImageRealPath);
        Glide.with(AddNewPostActivity.this).load(getImageRealPath).into(imageView);
    }
}
```

**Forgetting image real path**

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    try {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(idx);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Hope this help you...if you need any help you can ask

Comment: I am using Picasso:
`Picasso.with(mContext).load(Uri.parse(imagesList.get(currentPosition))).resize(135,135).centerCrop().into(holder.selfie_Imageview);`

Comment: @XoXo no problem you can use it.

Comment: try this: Picasso.with(mContext).load(Uri.parse(getImageRealPath).resize(1‌​35,135).centerCrop()‌​.into(holder.selfie_‌​Imageview);

Comment: I have provided the real path only but not loading:
`content://com.example.sravanthiv.consumermobileapp_nonclinical_android.fileprovider/all_dirs/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20171226_161309.jpg`

Comment: It's not real image path. real image path only DCIM/Ca‌​mera/IMG_20171226_16‌​1309.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162867/discussion-between-mahesh-vayak-and-xoxo).